# If hot air expands in all directions why is the balloon moving up?

Tags: pressure, temperature, air, density, buoyancy

A balloon is moving up. The hot air inside the balloon is expanding in all directions and cold air outside the balloon acts with force on the balloon from all directions (higher pressure force). Why is the balloon moving up then?

[image]

Comment: [Buoyancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy#Balloons).

Comment: @ACuriousMind I understand that if object is in water A slightly higher pressure acting on the bottom cause it to move up but I can't understand how is the hot air inside baloon causing it to move up. If air moves from high to low pressure shouldn't baloon implode or something

Comment: Balloons do explode. A very well sealed child's helium balloon will rise and rise, expanding as it rises, and eventually POP! What you're missing is that buoyancy is always a consequence of a pressure gradient. There would be no buoyancy if the pressure was the same at the top and bottom of the balloon, which is what your diagram suggests.

Comment: @David Hammen So hot air inside baloon causes more pressure at the top of the baloon? Why is that considering gravity pulls down air shouldn't pressure be increased at the bottom of baloon or shouldn't pressure be the same everywhere considering air at the bottom of baloon exert the same force upward and downward?

Comment: No! You are looking at the wrong object. It's the atmosphere that exhibits a pressure gradient (the balloon does too, but that's not the point). Without that pressure gradient in the atmosphere, there is no buoyancy. Think of that blue arrow at the bottom of your diagram being a tiny, tiny bit longer than the blue arrow at the top. That's what causes buoyancy.

Comment: @David Hammen But if there would be cool air inside baloon it would not rise. That's what I have problem with. I ve found this http://www.sprangle.com/steve/0606121706.htm He says that less upward gradient inside balloon than outside baloon causes it to lift but: 1.Isn't that inside gradient force a force that works on something inside baloon and not baloon itself 2.How less upward gradient cause it to lift 3. If atoms at the bottom and top works with the same pressure in every direction shouldn't the total force of hot air inside baloon exerted on the baloon be 0?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, a primer over what "buoyancy" is is needed. Pressure decreases with altitude. The atmospheric pressure at the top of the balloon is a tiny bit less than the atmospheric pressure at the bottom of the balloon. This pressure difference results in a tiny net upward force on the balloon. The balloon rises if this tiny net upward force exceeds the tiny weight of the balloon.

The balloon doesn't always move up. Try releasing a hot air balloon in Los Angeles or Denver or Mexico City. Oftentimes the balloon will rise maybe a thousand feet and then just stop. This indicates the atmosphere is stable, and it's why Los Angeles, Denver, and Mexico City have such serious problems with smog.

A hot air balloon rises when the [environmental lapse rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate#Environmental_lapse_rate) is sufficiently high. Air is a relatively lousy conductor of heat. This means the balloon doesn't transfer much heat with the external environment. The conditions inside the balloon more or less change adiabatically. Assuming the balloon is filled with air (as opposed to helium or hydrogen), the balloon will be buoyed upward so long as the temperature inside the balloon remains higher than the temperature of the surrounding air. The balloon stops rising shortly after the lapse rate of the surrounding air is less than that of the adiabatic drop that's happening inside the balloon.

Air temperature tends to decrease with increasing altitude. That "tends to" is key. The temperature profile eventually flattens out. Sometimes the altitude at which this happens is dozens of kilometer up, at very top of the troposphere. The boundary between the top of the troposphere and bottom of the stratosphere is where the tropospheric lapse rate stops. Temperatures rise with increasing altitude in the stratosphere. This is the key reason weather generally doesn't reach into the stratosphere. It takes a very large and very powerful thunderstorm to punch through the tropopause, the boundary that marks the top of the troposphere / bottom of the stratosphere.

Other times, this transition to a stable temperature happens at much lower altitudes (e.g., Los Angeles, Denver, and Mexico City).